# Rewriting URL using .htaccess and mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I used this code in my .htaccess to rewrite my urls which is like this:

`www.example.com/subcategory.php?subcat=my-test` 

to 

`www.example.com/my-test`

.htaccess code I used:

`RewriteEngine on`

`RewriteCond $1 !^(subcategory\.php|resources|robots\.txt)`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subcategory.php?subcat=$1 [L,QSA]`

My problem is whenever I access the url not pertaining to my subcategory.php file like contactus and aboutus, the .htaccess file will somehow put me to subcategory.php file which is not what I want. I want my contactus be handled by contactus.php and aboutus with aboutus.php.

I know that there is something wrong with my .htaccess file but I couldn't fix it by myself for I am not so familiar with the .htaccess coding.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are rewriting all requests to subcategory.php. There is no way for `.htaccess` to tell whether `/xxx` is a subcategory or some different page, so you could redirect it to a different script.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

Use this code snippet instead of yours and move all the "routing" logic to PHP. In PHP, you can find out whether /xxx is a subcategory, a contact page, an article or something else and use a script suitable for that kind of database record.

You will find the requested URL in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.